# Use a property of an interface as reference to retrieve another property value of the same interface

Tags: arrays, typescript, interface, key

In TypeScript, if I have an interface (or an array? Not keen on terminologies) like this:

```
export const AnimalColours = [
    { value: 'blue', desc: 'Blue Whale' },
    { value: 'black', desc: 'Black Bear' },
    { value: 'orange', desc: 'Orange Cat' },
] as IAnimalColours[]
```

On the UI, I have a variable that will have any value of the string that must correspond to the `AnimalColours.value`:

```
let inputOrEventValue: string = "orange" // can be taken from input or event
```

How do I get to output the description by referencing inputOrEventValue to AnimalColours?

```
let outPutstring: string = // My value Must use AnimalColours.value
```

#### Pseudo:

If inputOrEventValue has a value

Compare with AnimalColours.value

If EQUAL, return AnimalColours.desc

So that if  `inputOrEventValue = orange`

The `outPutstring` would take `AnimalColours[2].desc` (value: "Orange Cat")

#### One solution is:

```
for (animalColour in IAnimalColours) {
  if (animalColour.value ===  InputOrEventValue) {
    outputString = animalColour.desc;
  }
}
```

Are there other, more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So far the best I can do is:

```
this.animalColours.forEach(element => {
 if (this.inputOrEventValue === element.value) {
  this.outputString = element.desc;
 }
});
```

Feel free to post any other answer.